# Searching a protocol for self-organization and synchronization

Tags: synchronization, protocols, self-organization

Assume a task that has to be executed by a number of hardware devices. The task (detecting an electrical failure that might cost human lives and is thus) is very ***important*** and must ***reliably*** be executed ***regularly***. Every time one of the devices executes the task, the ***others must not*** do so. The devices are controlled by small computers. There might just be a single device/controller pair, or ***any number*** of them which need to coordinate. Controllers communicate by sending messages via a broker. Sending messages takes varying time, messages might get lost, device/controller pairs ***might come in and drop out*** unexpectedly at any time and with no warning. The controllers are rather weak embedded machines. Yet each of them must execute the task at least once every ${TIME}, and none of the others must do so at the same time.

What would be a good, simple, and reliable protocol for the brokers to sync with each other so that the above criteria are fulfilled?

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to be a good question for [SO]. I suppose it touches on distributed systems (transactions) and there might be specialized hardware circuitry with the proper redundancy checks to support this kind of reliability. Did you consider posting under [CS.SE], [Electronics.SE] or even (gasp) [Programmers.SE]?

Comment: (OT: Oh hey apparently `Programmers.SE` got relabeled there!)